# xdebug 2.2.1 installed but not working with cgi

Tags: configuration, php

I've installed (via pecl) xdebug. It is installed (as phpinfo() output indicates), but it doesn't seems to work with CGI (with CLI it works). I've restarted apache, without result. Any ideas?

Some config details (as parsed by http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

```
Xdebug installed: 2.2.1
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.3.10-1
Zend API nr: 220090626
PHP API nr: 20090626
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php5/apache2
Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the php.ini file listed in your config details (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini), you will find a line starting 'zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/' and ending with 'xdebug.so"'. Copy this line into your cgi php.ini file, probably at /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini